# how do I make this LINQ query faster?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

modelData has 100,000 items in the list.

I am doing 2 "Selects" within 2 loops.

Could it be structured differently - as it take a long time - 10 mins

```
public class ModelData
{
    public string name;
    public DateTime DT;
    public int real;
    public int trade;
    public int position;
    public int dayPnl;
}

List<ModelData> modelData;

var dates = modelData.Select(x => x.DT.Date).Distinct();
var names = modelData.Select(x => x.name).Distinct();

foreach (var aDate in dates)
{
    var dateRealTrades = modelData.Select(x => x)
                                  .Where(x => x.DT.Date.Equals(aDate) && x.real.Equals(1));

    foreach (var aName in names)
    {
        var namesRealTrades = dateRealTrades.Select(x => x)
                                            .Where(x => x.name.Equals(aName));

        // DO MY PROCESSING
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove `.Select(x => x)` for a start.

Comment: I think you just want one query that groups by the date and then by the name.

Comment: And unnecessary or redundant `.Distinct` could hurt performance.  That often forces sorting of the underlying data.  Make sure there's no other way to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: where clause x.real.Equals(1) should be executed before the foreach

Comment: Besides optimizing your Linq queries, you should definitely make sure that you have a covering index on your relevant DB fields. This will probably speed up your process by >90%. 100k rows really isn't such a big number.

Comment: @Robert can you explain further please - what is a covering index?

Comment: @Robert The real problem is that assuming that the query is iterated in the `// DO MY PROCESSING` this results in n times m sql queries where n is the number of unique dates and m is the number of unique names.

Comment: Unless you need to edit aName, change the foreach loop to names.ToList().ForEach.

Comment: @tdbeckett And why should he do that??

Comment: Ivan Stoev List<T>.ForEach is actually not the same as foreach-statement internally (you can check that with Reflector). Instead, it's a plain for-statement over list indices.   For loops are faster than foreach

Comment: @tdbeckett Please don't make me laugh. I know what `List<T>.ForEach` is. You'd better use Reflector to see how **your** code using that method looks like compared to simple *foreach*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want can be achieved with two queries using group by.  One to create a lookup by the date and the other to give you the name-date grouped items.

```
var data = modelData.Where(x => x.real.Equals(1))
                    .GroupBy(x => new { x.DT.Date, x.name });
var byDate = modelData.Where(x => x.real.Equals(1))
                      .ToLookup(x => x.DT.Date);

foreach(var item in data)
{
    var aDate = item.Key.Date; 
    var aName = item.Key.name;
    var namesRealTrades = item.ToList();
    var dateRealTrades = byDate[aDate].ToList();

    // DO MY PROCESSING
}
```

The first query will give you items grouped by the name and date to iterate over and the second will give you a lookup to get all the items associated with a given date.  The second uses a lookup so that the list is iterated once and gives you fast access to the resulting list of items.

This should greatly reduce the number of times you iterate over `modelData` from what you currently have.

Comment: Thank you. But for each date I also need the last "position" and "dayPnl". How may I adapt your code to add those in?

Comment: @ManInMoon Are you saying you use `dateRealTrades` inside the `// DO MY PROCESSING`?

Comment: I've updated to include a second query to get you a lookup for the items by Date.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your for loop like this:

```
foreach (var namesRealTrades in names.Select(aName => dateRealTrades.Where(x => x.name.Equals(aName))))
{
   //DO STUFF
}
```

Depending on your data this could reduce the number of queries you have to make

Comment: I do not see why that would make it faster - could you explain please?

Comment: Depending on your data it would reduce the number of query calls to the database. The only way to know for sure, is to try it out

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to compile your query as suggested on MSDN WebSite?

> When you have an application that executes structurally similar
>   queries many times, you can often increase performance by compiling
>   the query one time and executing it several times with different
>   parameters. For example, an application might have to retrieve all the
>   customers who are in a particular city, where the city is specified at
>   runtime by the user in a form. LINQ to SQL supports the use of
>   compiled queries for this purpose.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399335(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- use .ToList() to calculate a sequence once, so you can keep it for later.
- use .GroupBy() to avoid re-searching modelData for things you have already found.

  ```
  // Collections of models having the same Date or Name.
  var dates = modelData.GroupBy(x => x.DT.Date);
  var names = modelData.GroupBy(x => x.Name);

  foreach (var modelsWithDate in dates)
  {
     var aDate = modelsWithDate.Key;
     var dateRealTrades = modelsWithDate.Where(x => x.real == 1).ToList();

     foreach (var modelsWithName in names)
     {
         var aName = modelsWithName.Key;
         var namesRealTrades = modelsWithName.ToList();

         // DO MY PROCESSING
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Adding ToList() to var dates = modelData.GroupBy(x => x.DT.Date); and the next line would make sure they are pulled in to memory before looping them as well.

Comment: if you look at the question, modelData is already a List. Everything is already in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways the code is ineffective.

- names has deffered evaluation. Every time You iterate over it, it has to go though the whole data to find all the distinct names again. You should save the result.
- You find distinct values from collection and then You go through collection again for every distinct value and look fot its occurences. You should use grouping.

the rewritten code can look like this

```
    var dates = modelData.GroupBy(x => x.DT.Date);
    var names = modelData.Select(x => x.name).Distinct().ToArray();

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        var dateRealTrades = date.Where(x => x.real.Equals(1)).ToArray();
        var namesRealTradesLookup = dateRealTrades.ToLookup(x => x.name);

        foreach (var aName in names)
        {
            var namesRealTrades = namesRealTradesLookup[aName];

            // DO MY PROCESSING
            // var aDate = date.Key;
        }
    }
```

In case You are not interestested in date/name combination with no real trade, it can be done in much more straightforward way

```
    var realModelData = modelData.Where(x => x.real.Equals(1));

    foreach (var dateRealTrades in realModelData.ToLookup(x => x.DT.Date))
    {
        foreach (var namesRealTrades in dateRealTrades.ToLookup(x => x.name))
        {

            // DO MY PROCESSING
            //var aDate = dateRealTrades.Key;
            //var aName = namesRealTrades.Key;
            //foreach(var trade in namesRealTrades) { ...
            //foreach(var trade in dateRealTrades) { ...
        }
    }
```